# What is the maximum value for mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, mapreduce

When I set mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb = 100000. I get following exception.

```
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Invalid "mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb": 100000
```

What is the maximum value for mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb?

Answer (score 10):

I realize this question is old, but for those asking the same question you can check out some of the bugs around this value being capped

http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.3/bk_releasenotes_hdp_2.1/content/ch_relnotes-hdpch_relnotes-hdp-2.1.1-knownissues-mapreduce.html

BUG-12005: Mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb is capped at 2047.

Problem: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb is hardcoded to not allow values larger than 2047. If you enter a value larger then this the map tasks will always crash at this line:

https://github.com/apache/hadoop-mapreduce/blob/HDFS-641/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/MapTask.java?source=cc#L746

Answer (score 4):

hadoop-2.6.0 org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.java

[line 427:we can't set mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb exceed 2047](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl066.png)

Answer (score 0):

"mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb" is the total amount of buffer memory to use while sorting files, in megabytes. By default, gives each merge stream 1MB, which should minimize seeks. So you need to ensure you have 100000 MB memory available on the Cluster nodes.

Comment: I have much more memory available on my node(2 TB, to be exact. Yes believe me, it is 2 TB). 
Is there any other parameter which creates bound for mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb?

Answer (score 0):

By default it is 100MB and it can go up to 2047 MB.